# Saving codable struct in Userdefaults returns nil values upon fetching

Tags: ios, swift

Saving data in defaults:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(user) {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(encoded, forKey: DefaultKeys.user)
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

fetching data but getting nil keys of struct.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if let savedPerson = defaults.object(forKey: DefaultKeys.user) as? Data {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let loadedPerson = try? decoder.decode(UserModel.self, from: savedPerson) {
        return loadedPerson
    }
}
```

I tried to google the approaches everyone suggest the same to save custom object in **userdefaults**, but the approach is not working for me.Given below is my struct model which conform **Codable** as well.

```
struct UserModel : Codable {

var userDetails : UserDetail?
var status : Bool?
var message : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case userDetails = "userDetails"
    case status = "status"
    case message = "message"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    userDetails = try UserDetail(from: decoder)
    status = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .status)
    message = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message)
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share your user model class/struct?

Comment: And try adding `else` blocks to see if you are getting any error.

Comment: As @OlcayErtaş mentioned, add else blocks to check for any errors, I usually when encounter errors like these instead of `try?` I force the app to crash using `try!` making a lot easier to debug the problem

Comment: No, don't add `else` blocks, instead add a `do - catch` block, remove the question mark after `try` and `print(error)` in the `catch` scope.  It tells you what's wrong. And there is `data(forKey:` in UserDefaults. And don't call `synchronize`. The framework syncs the database periodically on your behalf.

Comment: @OlcayErtaş i tried catch block and else but no error over there, it does save and get the userModel struct but the issue is when i see the properties after fetch these all are null.

Comment: @vadian already tried all of the suggestion but nothing works so far.

Comment: The `catch` block catches errors only if `try?` is replaced with `try`. And what is `UserDetail`? And why is everything optional? And use the debugger. Set breakpoints and watch variables.

Comment: @vadian tried with 'try' also . When i see variables in debugger there is also nil values.
UserDetail is another struct which conform to codable and contains other model keys.